# How to tell Weblate that a particular string is a plural one

Tags: localization, translation, gettext, plural, weblate

I'm using ini file for localisation. Actually almost the Joomla! format.
I searched the Weblate documentation and read all about Gettext plural formulas for different languages.
What I can't find is how to "tell" Weblate that a particular string id is a plural.
I basically extended the ini to include something like this:

```
APPLE[1]="I have 1 apple"
APPLE[2]="I have 2 apples"
APPLE[3-...]="I have %d apples"
```

I need to know how to tell Weblate that APPLE[NUMBER] is a plural string.

Any idea how to do this?

Regards,
Radek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file format has to support plurals. The capabilities of supported formats are documented in https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/formats.html#translation-types-capabilities

If you are inventing the own way of storing plurals, you would have to implement support for it in Weblate as well. Or just choose one of existing formats which are widely used.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it is possible to implement it through customisation or is it necessary to modify Weblate itself?

Comment: You can implement file format support as a customization.

Comment: Thanks, very appreciated. Will try to find.

Comment: Hey Michal, I just realised who you are. Many thanks for an amazing piece of software. It's awesome!